# How to programatically toggle the media setting "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders"?

Tags: media

How can I programmatically change this setting?
[image: admin settings page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (database) option name for that setting is `uploads_use_yearmonth_folders`, so you can use `update_option()` to programmatically change the setting's value:

```php
// 1 to enable the "checked" state
update_option( 'uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', 1 );
```

You can also use a filter hook such as [`option_<name>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/option_option/):

```php
add_filter( 'option_uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', function ( $value ) {
    return 1; // 1 = checked
} );
```

Or am I not understanding the question? :)